# Why is the .navigationDestination block of NavigationStack executed twice in one screen push?

Tags: swiftui

I am having trouble with the strange behavior of `NavigationStack`.

I have implemented navigation using `NavigationStack` and `NavigationPath`.
The problem is that the `.navigationDestination` block is executed twice in one screen push.
This causes the `SecondView` initialization to be executed twice, resulting in unintended behavior.

Here is a demo program.

```swift
import SwiftUI

final class NavigationPathHolder: ObservableObject {
    @Published var navigationPath: NavigationPath = .init()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var navigationPathHolder = NavigationPathHolder()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationPathHolder.navigationPath) {
            Button {
                let randomNumber = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
                print("Tapped \(randomNumber)")
                navigationPathHolder.navigationPath.append(randomNumber)
            } label: {
                Text("Tap me")
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { number in
                let _ = print("Called \(number)")
                SecondView(number: number)
            }
        }
        .environmentObject(navigationPathHolder)
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationPathHolder: NavigationPathHolder

    let number: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(number)")
    }
}
```

The results is this.

```
Tapped 65
Called 65
Called 65

Tapped 48
Called 48
Called 48

Tapped 97
Called 97
Called 97
```

Why is this happening?
Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI you should never assume that a views initializer is only called once.

By design, SwiftUIs approach to use structs for declaring the layout, causes views to get initialized all the time, over and over again. Mind, a SwiftUI "View" is only the declaration of a view, it's not actually a "real object" like a UIView used to be.

That also means: everything is ok, nothing is wrong, you don't have to "fix" anything and you won't get a "double push" to the NavigationStack.

Edit with some background information:

An easy way to understand this is just by looking at the `body` of a view. In that `var body: some View`, you are defining what views are in there. E.g. a `VStack` with 2 `Texts` inside

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 8) {
        Text("some")
        Text("text")
    }
}
```

Now, each view also is a `struct`. That means `VStack` and `Text` are `structs` as well. And the way you place a view in the body is by using the `init` of that struct. Like `Text("some")`. However the `body` is a computed property. So each time the `body` is read by the layout system, it evaluates that computed property, calling all those initializers again. (Simplified. SwiftUI does some magic to find out whether it needs to relayout things or can be lazy. But generally assume this is happening.)